# How to configure Release path in Microsoft Release Management 2013 to deploy only to QA environment?

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

I have been successful in creating a release path from `DEV -> QA` environment deployment. The problem that I am facing is how do I deploy the changes only to a specific environment, like skipping DEV. No doubt that its possible with DEV environment alone (since its the first one).

I tried creating a new Release Path only for QA, but whenever I change the Release path only to QA the settings (toolbox) created vanishes.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported.
What you can do is, create the release in draft and skip all activities in the DEV stage and start the release. That way, the only thing to take care of would be the approvals/manual interventions.

Comment: That kind of works but not it doesnt seems to be the best way.

Answer (score 3):

This totally defeats the purpose of the tool. The entire point of defining a release path is that you **can't** skip stages, because you **shouldn't** skip stages. Skipping stages is exactly how we get into trouble in the first place.

"Oh, it's not a big deal, I'll just make the change directly in production"

10 minutes later...

"Why is production down?"

Comment: I totally agree with you Daniel. But there are times when we need to skip DEV or QA environment deployments. For instance, certain code changes  cannot be tested in DEV environment but can be tested only in QA environment. In those cases there is no need to deploy changes to DEV.